# Convert a 2D autonomous ODE system into a 1D system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have two equations:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(2-x-y),\,   
\frac{dy}{dt} = ky(2-ax-by)$$

that together form a 2D ODE system ($x$ plotted against $y). K, a$ and $b$ are all independent positive parameters. However, I am only interested in points at the line where $y = 3 \text{(or some other constant)} - x,\, $ as I am simulating a field that is always fully occupied by both $x$ and $y$ with no empty spaces.  Is there a possibility to reduce the whole system to only this line, e.g. make the 2D system into a 1D line that is a good representation of the system in 2D at this line?

Comment: why should a solution starting at the line stay on it?

Comment: Because then you conserve x + y = some constant value. If it would move away from that line, x+y would also change, which in this case I don't want. Imagine it as a field of a certain, finite area, fully filled with blue and red species, with no empty space between the species. So when the red species expand, the amount of blue species must decrease and vice versa, as the total space is limited. So, in the 2D system I have now I get unrealistic outcomes as either the maximal space is exceeded or empty space exists.

Comment: but $\frac{d}{dt}(x+y) = 2x-x^2 - xy + 2ky -akxy -bky^2 \neq 0.$ how is $x+y$ conserved?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem I am facing now, x + y is not conserved, but I'd want to make it so! In the current system x + y is obviously not conserved (unless R = -x/y, b = y/x and a = 1 I believe, but then my R and b variables are not independent anymore, which they should be), but isn't this somehow possible when I reduce the dimension? I mean when I plot the system, I could draw a line in it where y = x - constant, take my initial values on that line and then I'd want to stay on that line.